# Errors Using Eclipse for Android Development

Tags: java, android, eclipse, mobile

I'm working on Android development for the first time and I have a couple sample apps I've been running to make sure Eclipse is configured correctly, so I know it's not the code that's causing these issues. I keep on getting these two errors when I try to build:

1) R cannot be resolved to a variable

From what I've read, this will go away once I've successfully built a version, and R.java is created. If I've misunderstood this, please let me know.

2) error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'

This one I understand to be the main issue. I've read a bunch of different answers here, this looks like a common problem, but I can't get mine to work out. [I assume the issue has to do with this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9nURG.png)

Please help steer me in the right direction, I've been googling this all day and tried a ton of stuff but it's just not working. Thanks for any help!

Comment: to make it easier **dont use any theme for now** in your project and make sure you use the **correct imports** in your Java files i.e `com.yourpkg.R` instead of `android.R`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add support v7  library to use that kind of themes(Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar)

you need to add appcompat v7 as library project

if your style has an error eclipse does not generate R.java file

Answer (score 0):

These problem occurs mainly when you are doing these things:

1. Whenever android.R file is imported BY DEFAULT or BY YOURSELF in yours code than delete these line using (CONTROL+D) than after clean build the project. And than after when you move cursor on the line like setContentView(R.layout.your_layout) on "R" than eclipse give you two option first is import android.R and another import YOUR_PROJECT_NAME.home.r THAN YOU  SHOUL HAVE SELECT THE SECOND ONE AAND RESOLVE YOUR PROBLEM.
2. The problem can be occur when you do something wrong in the layout(in the xml file) than correct it and than again clean and build project.

Answer (score 0):

1.Try to **Project** - > **Clean**.

2. Download in Android SDK Manager latest version '**Android Support Library**' .